# Preserve Last-Modified in Docker

Tags: docker, time, makefile

How can I preserve the last-modified fields in a docker image, or at least set them to the time of docker image creation?  Currently all files in the container get last-modified set to the time of docker container instantiation.

A bit of background...

I'm working on a simple dockerized build system based on Make. The repo I'm building as well as the build outputs are all stored on my host system and keep a persistent last-modified date. But the SDK files are in the docker image and so have a last-modified date equal to "now".

The issue is that every time I run this docker-make, the whole SDK gets rebuilt because the last-modified time of all the files in the SDK is newer than rest of the project... even though they are the same old files as when the docker image was created.

I can recursively doctor the last-modified date of all of the files in the SDK at runtime, but that takes forever.

Is there a way that I can set these last-modified dates to some other time during the image build process?  Ideally, the last-modified dates of these files would equal the time of the docker image creation.

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. I am not sure I understand. Is it the SDK that gets rebuilt or is it the project? I mean, if the SDK files are newer than everything else, why are they rebuilt?

Comment: Did you consider excluding these files which last modification date is not persistent from the prerequisites of your Makefiles? Or declaring them as [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types)?

Comment: The way Make works is that it rebuilds new stuff, so all the files with the new dates get rebuilt.  It's like rebuilding the entire c standard lib every time you want to compile anything.  The SDK is in the docker, and it is set at the time of image creation... the problem is that the the last-modified time on all the SDK files are set to container creation time, not the image creation time.

Comment: The order-only prerequisites idea is a good one... but the SDK is more complex than that as it has make includes, which I believe also get a spot in the topological sort.  Also, the make includes extend to both sides of the docker boundary, so I would still have this issue in make files that are part of the SDK, and therefore not something that I want to modify.